# Using OpenCV to create a Neural network?

Tags: opencv, neural-network

I am working on creating a Real-time image processor for a self driving small scale car project for uni, It uses a raspberry pi to get various information to send to the program to base a decision by.

the only stage i have left is to create a Neural network which will view the image displayed from the camera ( i already have to code to send the array of CV_32F values between 0-255 etc.

I have been scouring the internet and cannot seem to find any example code that is related to my specific issue or my kind of task in general (how to implement a neural network of this kind), so my question is is it possible to create a NN of this size in c++ without hard coding it (aka utilising openCv's capabilities): it will need 400 input nodes for each value (from 20x20 image) and produce 4 outputs of left right fwd or backwards respectively.

How would one create a neural network in opencv?
Does openCV provide a backpropogation(training) interface /function or would I have to write this myself.

once it is trained am I correct in assuming I can load the neural network using ANN_MLP load etc? following this pass the live stream frame (as an array of values) to it and it should be able to produce the correct output.

edit:: I have found this [OpenCV image recognition - setting up ANN MLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500713/opencv-image-recognition-setting-up-ann-mlp). and It is very simple in comparison to what I want to do, and I am not Sure how to adapt that to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is not a neural network framework and in turn won't find any advanced features. It's far more common to use a dedicated ANN library and combine it with OpenCV. [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) is a great choice as a computer vision dedicated deep learning framework (with C++ API), and it can be [combined with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html).